# Question related to matrices

Tags: matrices

Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be two positive $2 \times 2$ matrices. Suppose $s$ and $t$ are another $2 \times 2$ complex invertible matrices such that $s^*s+t^*t=I$ and satisfies
$$e_{11}=s^*\mu s+t^* \nu t.$$ Can we conclude that $\mu_{22}=\nu_{22}=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a counter-example.
$$
        s =t= \begin{pmatrix}
            0 &  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
            \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} } &  0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}, \quad 
        \mu = \nu = \begin{pmatrix}
            0 &  0 \\
            0 &  1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$